# Split audio file with cue sheet

Tags: audio

I've got a large audio file in MPEG-4/MP4 format (`file foo.m4b` returns `foo.m4b: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]` and `mpv` indicates that it's two-channel, AAC at 44.1kHz) and a corresponding cue sheet. I want to split the audio file into the tracks described in the cue sheet.

How can I do this from within macOS 10.13.6? I'm familiar with XLD, but that seems only to provide the ability to burn to physical media given a cue sheet. Homebrew offers `cuetools`, but these seem to deal only with the cue sheet itself and not the audio file it relates to.

Comment: How is this related to Apple?

Comment: @Allan Edited the question to reflect the environment.

Comment: I've never tried this, so I'm hesitatant to give an answer.  However, have a look at this - it should work on a Mac.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/how-do-i-split-a-flac-with-a-cue